# Which jQuery events do not bubble?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Pretty straightforward, I've been searching high and low for a comprehensive list of all jQuery events that do not bubble but I have been unable to find one.

For example I am looking for events like `image.load`, `XMLHttpRequest.error`, etc.

Comment: Has nothing to do with jQuery since jQuery is JavaScript.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-types-list

Comment: @j08691 - That depends, jQuery adds bubbling to some events that doesn't normally bubble.

Comment: @j08691 unfortunately that's not correct. Due to the inconsistencies of browser event implementation, the jQuery.Event object serves as a surrogate for actual browser events. An example of this are the `blur` and `focus` events, which do not bubble in normal js, but do bubble (under aliased event names) in jQuery

Comment: I misunderstood what you were after.

Comment: http://help.dottoro.com/larrqqck.php, may be this list handy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The docs for jQuery's `on()` method says this](http://api.jquery.com/on/#additional-notes) (under "Additional Notes");

> The `focus` and `blur` events are specified by the W3C to not bubble, but jQuery defines cross-browser `focusin` and `focusout` events that do bubble. When `focus` and `blur` are used to attach delegated event handlers, jQuery maps the names and delivers them as `focusin` and `focusout` respectively. For consistency and clarity, use the bubbling event type names.
>
> **In all browsers, the `load`, `scroll`, and `error` events (e.g., on an `<img>` element) do not bubble. In Internet Explorer 8 and lower, the `paste` and `reset` events do not bubble.** Such events are not supported for use with delegation, but they can be used when the event handler is directly attached to the element generating the event.

I've **bolded** the most relevant sentences for emphasis.

Earlier in the docs (under "direct and delegated events", it also says this:

> In Internet Explorer 8 and lower, a few events such as `change` and `submit` do not natively bubble but jQuery patches these to bubble and create consistent cross-browser behavior.

You'll also find that [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave) and [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter) do not bubble (use the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events for that). This is discussed in their respective docs.

I wouldn't begin to call the above list comprehensive, but it's a start. I'm not sure how XMLHttpRequest comes into it in your question; it isn't part of the DOM, therefore doesn't have any ancestors, therefore cannot really *bubble* in the same way as normal DOM events.

Comment: I appreciate the list given, but I need to store an actual array of event names that don't bubble for the purposes of event tracking with Google Analytics. Specifically, I need to know which events must be attached directly to the object vs those that can be delegated. A use-case for this in the context of XMLHttpRequest would be tracking `load` events on certain AJAX calls

Comment: @wvandaal: Why not always attach to the object? I still don't understand the use-case for XMLHttpRequest; the only way you can detect a XMLHttpRequest completing (AFAIK), outside of subscribing to onreadystatechange, is by waiting for a DOMSubtreeModified event, and assuming it was because of an AJAX call? I'm recommending alternative approaches because I'm not sure you'll ever get a complete list. There are hundreds of events if you consider non-standard, drafts, browser extensions, *then* you have events which bubble in some and not in others. It's quite a hard thing to achieve :)

Answer (score 1):

According to [DOM Level 3 Events spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-types-list),

- Events that bubble:

  `beforeinput`, `click`, `compositionstart`, `compositionupdate`, `compositionend`, `dblclick`, `focusin`, `focusout`, `input`, `keydown`, `keyup`, `mousedown`, `mousemove`, `mouseout`, `mouseover`, `mouseup`, `select`, `wheel`.
- Events that don't bubble:

  `abort`, `blur`, `error`, `focus`, `load`, `mouseenter`, `mouseleave`, `resize`, `scroll`<sup>(*)</sup>, `unload`

Note DOM Level 3 Events doesn't define all events, some of them are defined by HTML5 spec.

That spec is less clear, because doesn't always say if events bubble and defines some events in non-normative sections. In one of these it says that [drag-and-drop events](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#dndevents) bubble:

`dragstart`, `drag`, `dragenter`, `dragexit`, `dragleave`, `dragover`, `drop`, `dragend`.

---

<sup>(*) When dispatched on the `Document` element, `scroll` event type MUST bubble to the `defaultView` object.</sup>